# jsdoc failed parsing @param type

Tags: jsdoc

Hi I am trying to use **JSDoc** on a new project but it seems broken.

Step to reproduce the error.

Bootstrap a new project.

```
mkdir test-jsdoc
cd $_
touch index.js
npm install jsdoc
```

Then I edited the `index.js` file (using vi) :

```
/**
 * @param {string} str
 */
 function echo(str) {
   console.log(str);
 }
```

Check if JSDoc is installed

```
./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js -v
JSDoc 3.4.0 (Tue, 10 Nov 2015 00:28:09 GMT)
```

Call it over the file

```
./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js ./index.js 
ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file /home/tvba5179/test-jsdoc/index.js with tag title "param" and text "{string} str": Invalid type expression "string": parse is not a function
ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file /home/tvba5179/test-jsdoc/index.js with tag title "param" and text "{string} str": Invalid type expression "string": parse is not a function
```

Any hint ?

Comment: Unable to reproduce your error. Are you still experiencing it?

Comment: Yes, just gave it a try and i got the same behavior. I am running Ubuntu Xenial. I did try in a coworker's VM and I have the same behavior as well.

Comment: I've tried it in MacOSX, it works fine. 
The version I've tried: JSDoc 4.0.0